# C# Array.Resize Passing a Ref instead of a Value

Tags: c#, arrays

**Title might be a bit misleading**

I have a string array. That I would like to pass by reference.

I know it can be accomplished simply by

```
public class test{
    string[] content = {"abc", "abd"};
    ViewContent vc = new ViewContent();

    public static void Main()
    {
        vc.InitView(content);
    }
}

public class ViewContent{
     string[] contentToView;

     public void InitView(ref string[] contentToShow)
     {
         contentToView = contentToShow;
         View();
     }

     public void View()
     {
         //Do whatever with contentToView
         //Example
         Array.Resize<string> (ref contentToView, someInt);
     }
}
```

If I were to resize the array with

```
Array.Resize()
```

The reference breaks and any further edits upon the resized array is not reflected on the main array from `test` class.

My question is:
<strike>How do I prevent the reference to the main array from breaking when the need arises for me to resize it?</strike>
**Rephrase**
How do I resize `contentToView` while also resizing `content` in `test` class?

Yes, I know it would be simpler to use Lists but I am experimenting with Arrays.

Yes, I know my problems would be solved if I pass in the `test` object instead of just an array. I am avoiding this method because I have other objects that have string arrays as well. You might ask that if I have other objects, that serve similar functions I could use inheritance and take in the base class to ensure that all my content can be shown. This is something I would like to avoid.

Comment: Where is you Resize usage example?

Comment: Essentially the Array.Resize() method creates a new Array and replaces the old one with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I prevent the reference to the main array from breaking when the need arises for me to resize it?

You don't. You just don't use an array. Array objects aren't resizable, and after you've copied the value of `contentToShow` into `contentToView`, any further changes to the `contentToShow` variable are ignored, and likewise in reverse.

What you're asking is for `contentToView` to change its value (which is a reference) every time `content` in your `test` class changes, or vice versa. There's no way of achieving that. You could introduce another level of indirection with a `Wrapper<T>` class you'd write which basically looks like this:

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

If you then made `test.content` and `ViewContent.contentToView` both `Wrapper<string[]>` fields, then if you change `test.content.Value`, you'd see that change in `ViewContent.contentToView.Value`... but I would advise against it.

Comment: I am not actually asking for contentToView to change when content in test changes. I am actually asking to change content in test when I resize contentToView

Comment: @xwillflame: Well it's the same both ways round. They're independent variables.

Comment: So there really isn't an elegant and simple workaround if I am limiting myself to just working with arrays?

Comment: @xwillflame: Indeed. You already know several alternatives, so I suggest you use those.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to resize array itself. `Array.Resize` method creates new array. So in anyway your old reference will not work. Also there is no sense to use `ref` keyword in your code. It can be useful only if you will reassign `contentToShow` inside `InitView` method. You have to use some class (`List` or your own class) if you want to "resize" your array (reassign it to the new array).

Comment: Yes I actually do intend to edit the test class content in ViewContent class. Formatting reasons.